# remove max and min from list without copying list

Tags: python, list, subset

say I have this list

```
x = [2, 4, 1, 11]
```

if I want to KEEP only the max and min I can do

```
[i for i in x if i == max(x) or i == min(x)]
```

(returns `[1,11]`)

but then why doesn't this work to REMOVE only the max and min?

```
[i for i in x if i != max(x) or i != min(x)]
```

(returns `[2, 4, 1, 11]`)

Comment: `i` cannot be max and min at the same time, unless the list has only one element. Use `and` between the conditions instead of `or`, or `not(i == max(x) or i == min(x))` according to De Morgan's laws.

Comment: It can also be max and min at the same time if all elements are equal.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is

```
not (i == max(x) or i == min(x))
```

which simplifies to (notice `and` instead of `or`)

```
i != max(x) and i != min(x)
```

to understand why see [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Finally, your code is quite inefficient because it recomputes `min` and `max` every time. You can instead do:

```
extremes = [min(x), max(x)]
without_extremes = [i for i in x if i not in extremes]
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler to read if you did:

```py
x.remove(max(x))
x.remove(min(x))
```

Comment: Only removes one of each, though. And crashes if the list has size 1.